# Why are paragraphs interpreted differently using "{" and "}" motions vs. "ap" and "ip"?

Tags: vim

When using `{` or `}` to navigate between paragraphs, Vim appears to treat lines with white space characters as if they were part of the paragraph and skips past them. This behaviour has been discussed in a number of threads and the explanation given (based on `:h paragraph`) is that "a paragraph begins after each *empty* line", which is fine.

However, this does not appear to be consistent with the way Vim treats the `ap` and `ip` commands, which actually do treat lines with whitespace characters as paragraph breaks. For example, given the following text where the first two paragraphs are separated by a non-empty line (containing whitespace) and the second and third paragraphs are separated by an empty line (and assuming the cursor starts at the top of the buffer) the following occurs:

```
1  abc  # next line contains spaces
2      
3  def  # next line is blank
4  
5  jkl
```

- `}`: moves the cursor to line 4 (i.e., treats lines 1-4 as a paragraph)
- `dap`: deletes lines 1 and 2 (i.e., treats only lines 1-2 as a paragraph)

These two behaviours appear to be inconsistent with one another. Why do these two commands that operate on a `paragraph` object behave differently?

Comment: `:h ap` directly says that this is "an exception".

Comment: @Matt thanks, that's fair. Just trying to figure out why though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in `:help ap` and `:help ip`:

> Exception: a blank line (only containing white space) is also a paragraph boundary.

So the behaviour of `ap` was made voluntarily different from that of `}` and the difference is clearly documented. The exact reasoning behind that difference is explained nowhere, though, and may be lost in time. You might want to ask on Vim's official mailing list.

Anyway, we can extrapolate a little…

- Vim's `}` is consistent with vi's `}`. This is expected since Vim's whole purpose is, after all, to be a convincing stand-in for vi.
- `ap` (and the whole concept of text objects) is a Vim thing. It wasn't in vi so there is no existing behaviour to replicate and the person who added that feature decided to make it treat "paragraphs" in a slightly more intuitive fashion than `}`.